# invalid read of size 1

Tags: c++

Después de ver muchos hilos parecidos, no consigo solucionar adecuadamente este mensaje de error de Valgrind (memcheck):

```
==397018== Invalid read of size 1
==397018==    at 0x527689D: JUMP_TO_L3_EXT_HEADER(unsigned char const*, unsigned char, unsigned long) (ip_proto.h:628)
==397018==    by 0x5276A2B: JUMP_TO_L3_FRAG_HEADER(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) (ip_proto.h:654)
==397018==    by 0x5276B1D: GET_L3_FRAG_INFO_IPV6(unsigned char const*, unsigned int&, unsigned short&, unsigned char&, unsigned char&, unsigned long, unsigned char*) (ip_proto.h:668)
==397018==    by 0x5277744: packetinfo::L3PacketHandler::fill(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (L3PacketHandler.h:170)
==397018==    by 0x5277CA4: packetinfo::PacketInfo::fill(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, bool) (PacketInfo.h:292)
==397018==    by 0x5277E68: cdpi::protoengine::PacketInfoCache::fill(unsigned char*, unsigned int, bool) (PacketInfoCache.h:73)
==397018==    by 0x51621D3: cdpi::protoengine::ProtoEngine::initPacketPath(bool, unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int) (ProtoEngine.cc:3412)
==397018==    by 0x5224436: cdpi::FlowManager::FlowManagerPriv::getFlow(bool, unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, generic_addr const&, cdpi::ClassificationResult&, cdpi::L4Data*, cdpi::User*) (FlowManagerPriv.cc:205)
==397018==    by 0x5223D9E: cdpi::FlowManager::getFlow(bool, unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, generic_addr const&, cdpi::ClassificationResult&, cdpi::L4Data*, cdpi::User*) (FlowManager.cc:41)
==397018==    by 0x61C4B7: dpisim::CDPIFlavour::processPDUs(dpisim::DPIsimPolicyDecisor*, dpisim::DPIsimPacket&, dpisim::DPIsimPacketResult&, cdpi::ClassificationResult&, cdpi::AnalyzerContext&, int, dpisim::DPIsimUser&) (CDPIFlavour.cc:280)
==397018==    by 0x61C224: dpisim::CDPIFlavour::processPacket(dpisim::DPIsimPacket&, dpisim::DPIsimPacketResult&, dpisim::DPIsimUser&) (CDPIFlavour.cc:248)
==397018==    by 0x614D46: dpisim::DPIAdapter::processPacket(dpisim::DPIsimPacket&, dpisim::DPIsimPacketResult&, dpisim::DPIsimUser&) (DPIAdapter.cc:282)
==397018==  Address 0x7bdc5ef is 7 bytes after a block of size 56 alloc'd
==397018==    at 0x4A08982: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:385)
==397018==    by 0x5BAEAD: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::initialize(pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:215)
==397018==    by 0x5BA45F: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::DPIsimPacket(pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:42)
==397018==    by 0x5DF4A6: dpisim::DPIsimPacketManager::manipulatePacket(unsigned int, pcap_pkthdr*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacketManager.cc:102)
==397018==    by 0x5ADEC6: dpisim::DPIsimTracePcap::run() (DPIsimTracePcap.cc:134)
==397018==    by 0x5DEAC6: boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>::operator()(dpisim::DPIsimTrace*) const (mem_fn_template.hpp:49)
==397018==    by 0x5DE969: void boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>&, boost::_bi::list0&, int) (bind.hpp:255)
==397018==    by 0x5DE89C: boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> > >::operator()() (bind_template.hpp:20)
==397018==    by 0x5DE817: boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> > > >::run() (thread.hpp:116)
==397018==    by 0x6089D49: thread_proxy (in /lab/dpi/building-deps/boost/boost_1_59_0/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.59.0)
==397018==    by 0x3D45807AA0: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==397018==    by 0x3D454E893C: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
```

El código que causa el error es el de la línea indicada en el comentario:

```
inline const unsigned char* JUMP_TO_L3_EXT_HEADER(const unsigned char*     packet, uint8_t extHeader,size_t packetlen = 0) {
if(VERSION_IPv4 == IP_VERSION(packet)) {
return packet;
} else {
uint8_t current_header = IPPROTO_IPV6;

// Check packetlen
uint32_t size = 0;

while((extHeader!= current_header && (IPPROTO_IPV6 == current_header || IPPROTO_FRAGMENT == current_header ||
                                     IPPROTO_HOPOPTS == current_header || IPPROTO_ROUTING == current_header ||
                                     IPPROTO_DSTOPTS == current_header || IPPROTO_AH == current_header))) {

  if (packetlen!=0 && size>packetlen)
  {
     // Error calculating extension header size. Exit
    return NULL;
  }

  uint8_t next_header=IPPROTO_IPV6;
  switch(current_header) {
  case IPPROTO_IPV6:
    next_header = ((const ip6_hdr*)packet)->ip6_ctlun.ip6_un1.ip6_un1_nxt;
    packet += sizeof(const ip6_hdr);
    size += sizeof(const ip6_hdr);
    break;
  case IPPROTO_HOPOPTS:
  case IPPROTO_ROUTING:
  case IPPROTO_DSTOPTS:
    /* All these headers have the first 16 bits equal, so we can group them */
    next_header = ((const ip6_ext*)packet)->ip6e_nxt;
    packet +=  8 + ((((const ip6_ext*)packet)->ip6e_len)<<3); /* +1 because according to RFC size does not include the first 8 bytes */
    size += 8 + ((((const ip6_ext*)packet)->ip6e_len)<<3);//AQUÍ INDICA VALGRIND EL ACCESO INDEBIDO!!!
    break;        
  case IPPROTO_FRAGMENT:
    next_header = ((const ip6_ext*)packet)->ip6e_nxt;
    packet += sizeof(ip6_frag);
    size += sizeof(ip6_frag);
    break;
  case IPPROTO_AH:
    /* Authentication header does include the size in a different format that the rest of headers ... 
       Very smart thing to do in a standard! 
       The size is a 16 bit network-order word, which give you the number of 4-bytes words in size, minus 8*/
    next_header = ((const ip6_ext*)packet)->ip6e_nxt;
    packet += 8 + ((be16toh( ((*(packet+1))<<8) + *(packet+2)))<<2);
    size +=  8 + ((be16toh( ((*(packet+1))<<8) + *(packet+2)))<<2);
    break;
  }
  current_header = next_header;
} 
return (extHeader == current_header) ? packet : NULL;
}
}
```

Puse un printf para tratar de detectar el fallo. Da la siguiente salida:

```
size=48, ip6e_len=0, ip6e_len<<3=0
```

Cualquier sugerencia será bien aceptada.

Comment: Solucionado eliminando la variable size y modificando la condición if como indica eferion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En base al código que expones el problema se encuentra aquí:

```
const unsigned char* packet;
```

¿A dónde apunta ese puntero? a ninguna parte o a una posición aleatoria, como prefieras decirlo.

Después de declarar esa variable intentas manipular el puntero:

```
next_header = ((const ip6_ext*)packet)->ip6e_nxt;
```

Pero claro, si `packet` no apunta a nada en concreto... ¿Qué esperas recuperar de `packet->ip6e_next`? En el mejor de los casos recuperarás basura y en el peor el programa será abortado por el sistema operativo por intentar acceder a memoria que no te corresponde.

**EDITO:**

```
packet +=  8 + ((((const ip6_ext*)packet)->ip6e_len)<<3); /* +1 because according to RFC size does not include the first 8 bytes */
size += 8 + ((((const ip6_ext*)packet)->ip6e_len)<<3);//AQUÍ INDICA VALGRIND EL ACCESO INDEBIDO!!!
```

en la primera instrucción modificas el puntero `packet` y en la segunda intentas leer... ¿lo mismo que en la primera instrucción? como ya has modificado el puntero la lectura será distinta.

Si te fijas, el incremento de `packet` va a coincidir **siempre** con el valor de `size`. Yo creo que te puedes ahorrar la variable `size` y calcularla con aritmética de punteros:

```
uint8_t current_header = IPPROTO_IPV6;

const char* init = packet;

// ...

if (packetlen!=0 && (packet-init)>packetlen)
```

O eso o almacena el incremento a en una variable local y después aplica dicho valor a ambas variables.

Un saludo.

Comment: Lo que no termino de entender es por qué el error, me lo marca en la línea que empieza por "size +=" no en la línea "next_header =". El puntero "packet" se usa en varias ocasiones y solo se da error en la última línea.

Comment: Los mensajes de error de Valgrind dependen de los mecanismos que utilice para decirte dónde detecta posibles problemas de memoria. La detección de problemas en memoria no es una ciencia exacta y prueba de ello es que pueden aparecer falsos positivos. Tu cometido, más que analizar el motivo por el que el mensaje sale en una línea y no en otra,  es el de ser capaz de localizar el problema y solucionarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos aquí ;)

Comment: Había recortado el código perdiendo su significado, vuelvo a poner la función completa. el puntero "packet" se recibe como parámetro de la función. El problema sigue sin solucionar.

Comment: Es una variable local en la función:    uint32_t size = 0;

Comment: Solucionado con la propuesta editada de eferion. Mil gracias!